# Use a property or method to mark a class as special? (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, oop

In JavaScript, I want to mark object A as special, so that when A is accessed by B, B can check whether A is marked so that B treats A as different from other objects. (Think that B is a serializer that processes many different objects, and A has to be serialized in a certain way.)

Now, I can either 
1: set a property in A, e.g., A.special=true
2: define a method, e.g., A.isSpecial(), which if the method exists, it shows that A is special.

I know that both of these do the same thing. From the design point of view, are there any differences, which makes one preferable?

Comment: If all you're going to do is look for the presence of a property/method, then use a property. If you want/need to do something specific to determine it (like actually running code...maybe calculating the length of the object to determine if it's special, for example) and check its result, use a method. Using a method that has no purpose and is "empty" is just misleading.

Comment: Depends on the situation, but possibly you can directly test for the difference of A (the reason why A is so special) without setting an additional property.

Comment: And if you use a property, I'd choose a more meaningful name and not call it "special".

Answer (score 1):

> From the design point of view, are there any differences, which makes one preferable?

The boolean property is much simpler, and easier to test. If it is not defined, `A.special` will result in `undefined` which is falsy already.

If you'd use a method, you would need to test `typeof A.special == "function" && A.special()` as only `A.special()` would lead to an exception if the method was not defined.

The method solution would only be preferable if you'd need to dynamically calculate the specialness (it might depend on other properties?) and don't want to update a boolean flag always along with updating those properties. However, for that case there's also the middle way of using a getter property (if you don't need to support old IEs).

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the property is definitely faster:

```
this.special = true;
```

But outside `A`'s code, someone can do `A.special = false`. There's no way to prevent that.

Using a method forbids other objects to modify the value. In `A`'s constructor you can define:

```
...
var special = true;
...
this.isSpecial = function() {return special;};
```

In modern browsers, there's a way to get the best of both: `Object.defineProperty`. So you can define a property and forbid external sources to change it:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "special", {value: true, writable: false, configurable: false});
```

This isn't available in IE7 and lower, and in IE8 is defined only for DOM objects and using the `get` and `set` property definitions:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "special", {get: function() {return true;}});
```

This isn't faster than calling an `isSpecial` method.

Comment: "*forbid external sources to change it*" - not only *external* ones, it will prevent *any* attempt to change it.

Comment: @Bergi And that includes external sources :D But anyway, one can expect that you know what you're doing with your code.

Comment: Btw, you could modify the function return value as well by just overwriting it (`A.special = function(){return false;};`)

Answer (score -1):

Using a property `A.special = true;` is going to be faster (although I doubt this is a performance critical piece of code).

The advantage of doing a method `A.special = function() {...};` is that you get a layer of indirection and can put more advanced logic in there.  E.g.,

```
A.special = function() { return foo && bar && !baz ? true : false; };
```